# What is 2 pass and 1 pass hash table

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, time-complexity, hashtable

I was solving a ques on leetcode and after submitting my brute force solution, I looked up optimal solutions and found "two pass hash table" and "one pass hash table", as a novice programmer, I couldn't satisfactory explanation of what is one pass and two pass hash tables. Could somebody explain it.
https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solution/
(link to the leetcode question)

Comment: `pass` means iteration

Comment: You spelled queue wrong. *queue*, not *ques*.

Comment: It's not "N pass hash table", but "N-pass"es (i.e. `for` loops) over the input array, and separately - using a hash table.

Answer (score 3):

Hashtables, taken outside of the context of this problem, aren't "one pass" or "two pass".

This problem has created a new terminology of "passes" when they really should have said "used once" or "used twice".

Since their "better solution" stores items in a hash table, and then pulls them out, their "two pass" hash table is really "a hash table used twice for the solution"